# CasperJS - How does one selectively run tests from a folder/directory of testcases?

Tags: testing, casperjs, ui-automation

I have been looking at the various questions on Stack Overflow and the Casperjs documentation, but I havent been able to figure it out. The scenario is this - I have a set of JS files in a tests/ folder, of which I would like to do either of the following:- 
a) Run all of them [trivial and known already]
b) Pick selected test files to run [known, achieved by specifiying file paths as arguments to the "casperjs test" command]
c) Specify one or two file names, all files excluding these names need to get executed

c) is something I am not able to figure out if it is possible at all in the first place.  If yes, how does one go about it?  The use case for such a case is when I know that my application will not be behaving in a certain fashion due to pre-set(known) configurations/settings.

Comment: This is not something that can be solved with CasperJS. You will need your favorite scripting environment like bash or batch.